# vb.net datatable to excel with color

Tags: vb.net, backcolor

in vb.net i have datatable which the value from database here the format.

[image]

Is this possible when i want to make the style and color with the rules :

```
if nilai2 >= nilai1 then 
          hasil.backcolor = color.red
else if nilai2 < nilai1 then 
          hasil.backcolor = color.white
end if
```

Output : 
[image]

Thanks before

Comment: Please can you look at [ask] and consider making your question clearer. As it stands this question doesn't make much sense. What are you using to display the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have get the answer. Here my code :

```
xlrange = sobjSheet.Range(columnName & "2:" & columnName & "" & dgvhasil.RowCount + 1)
With xlrange
            .FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, "0")
            .FormatConditions(1).font.ColorIndex = 3
        End With
```

Thanks for your attentions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataGridView, you can probably do it with the RowPostPaint event.

In the example below, as soon as each row is painted in the DataGridView DataGridViewMaterial, the entire row is painted on a color that depends on the value of the column "MaterialState".

```
  Private Sub DataGridViewMaterial_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewMaterial.RowPostPaint

    Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGridViewMaterial.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    If dgvRow.Cells("MaterialState").Value <> "" Then
        With dgvRow.DefaultCellStyle
            Select Case dgvRow.Cells("MaterialState").Value
                Case 1
                    .BackColor = Color.White
                Case 2
                    .BackColor = Color.Orange
                Case 3
                    .BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
                Case 31
                    .BackColor = Color.Crimson
                Case 4, 41, 42
                    .BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
                Case 5
                    .BackColor = Color.LightPink
                Case 6
                    .BackColor = Color.YellowGreen
                Case 7
                    .BackColor = Color.Gray
                Case Else
                    .BackColor = Color.Red
            End Select
        End With
    End If
```

You can probably paint an individual cell with something like:

```
dgvRow.Cells("YourColumnName").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```